# python print string on multiple lines

Tags: python, string, file, io

I have a function that can only accept strings. (it creates the image with the string, but the string has little formatting and no word wrapping, so a long string will just bleed right through the edge of the image and keep going into the abyss, when in reality I would have liked it to create a paragraph, instead of a one line infinity).

I need it print with line breaks. Currently the file is being readin using

```
inputFiles.readlines()
```

so that this reads the entire file. Storing file.readLines() creates a list. So this list cannot be passed to my function looking for a string.

I used

```
inputFileContent = ' \n'.join(inputFiles.readLines())
```

in an attempt to force hard line breaks into the string between each list item. This does not work (edit: elaboration here) which means that the inputFileContent string does not have line breaks even though I put '\n' between the list elements. From my understanding, the readLines() function puts the individual lines into individual elements of a list.

any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: What is `inputfiles`? What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by it doesn't work. Show what it does and what you want it to do.

Comment: Please give information about the function you are calling.  Is it part of a library?  How is it documented to work?

Comment: I opened my input file in vi and noticed there are ^M where all the line breaks should be. How can I make python notice these too, currently it sees the entire file as one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'join' should have worked. Your problem may be that the writing of the string ignores newline characters. You could maybe try '\r\n'.join(...)

Comment: adding \r to the mix didn't do anything either, I just tried using "readLine()" to see if it was distinguishing and to my surprise, python is not seeing the hard returns within my inputFile

Comment: I got it working, my file needed to be read in with the U flag. Then python recognized the hard returns within the file.

Answer (score 4):

Use `inputFiles.read()` which creates a string.  Does that help?

Comment: Hey, there are worse things in life.

Comment: Yeah, like us both not making the next python meeting because it was booked before you replied... Oh, wrong chat window...